# How to convert Python Tensorflow Session Run Call to Tensorflow's C++ API

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow

I am trying to figure out how to call Tensorflow's C++ API.

I have the following Python code:

```
with open("logfile.txt", "w") as logFile:
    logFile.write("detection_boxes=" + str(detection_boxes))
    logFile.write("detection_scores=" + str(detection_scores))
    logFile.write("detection_classes=" + str(detection_classes))
    logFile.write("num_detections=" + str(num_detections))
    logFile.write("image_tensor=" + str(image_tensor))

(boxes, scores, classes, num) = sess.run(
    [detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections],
    feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})
```

where detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections, and image_tensor are Tensors.  When str() is applied for the print statement, they look like the following:

```
detection_boxes=Tensor("detection_boxes:0", dtype=float32)
detection_scores=Tensor("detection_scores:0", dtype=float32)
detection_classes=Tensor("detection_classes:0", dtype=float32)
num_detections=Tensor("num_detections:0", dtype=float32)
image_tensor=Tensor("image_tensor:0", shape=(?, ?, ?, 3), dtype=uint8)
```

However, it seems like Tensorflow's C++ API's Session Run() call has a different signature. In session.h,

virtual Status Run(const std::vector >& inputs, const std::vector& output_tensor_names, const std::vector& target_node_names, std::vector* outputs) = 0;

It seems like the C++ API expects vector instead of a list/collection of Tensors.

How can I call the C++ API with equivalent parameters as the Python code?

Thank you very much for your help in advance!